# JUnit test failing with BufferedWriter throwing an IOException

Tags: exception, junit, junit5, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I use JUnit 5 with maven and would like to do some stress tests involving file I/O.

In my JUnit test class, I have an `@BeforeAll` method which suppose to create the file that would be written in. However, when I run my tests, the `setup()` methods gives an Error

```
public class StressTest {
    String fileName = "stressTest.txt";
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;
    long start, finish, timeElapsed, iteration = 10;

    @BeforeAll
    public void setup() throws IOException {
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(fileName), true));
    }
...
}
```

The error message does not show the full name of the exception for some reason

`JUnit @BeforeAll method 'public void StressTest.setup() throws ja...`

I spent some time to troubleshoot but getting nowhere :( 
What could be the reason of the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the full message:

> @BeforeAll method 'public void StressTest.setup() throws java.io.IOException' must be static unless the test class is annotated with @TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS).

You should either convert it to a static method or use @Before instead of @BeforeAll.

By the way are you using an IDE?
Mine showed the full exception message.

Comment: ˋ@Beforeˋ does not exist in Jupiter. You probably mean ˋ@BeforeEachˋ

Comment: I use Intellij IDEA CE but also tried from the command line. Adding the file operations into `@BeforeEach` solved the issue. Thanks

Comment: Yes sorry I meant @BeforeEach (@Before was in Junit 4).
Glad to hear that it solved your problem!